# Mount --bind persistence over reboot

Tags: centos, mount

I'm having trouble finding an answer for this question

*Does mount --bind persist over reboot?*

On my CentOS it looks like it doesn't, so I've placed apropriate mount --bind calls in rc.local.

How can I do mount --bind to avoid rc.local scenario?

Comment: Why would you think a mount --bind would be any different than any other mount?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create an entry for the bound mount in your /etc/fstab.  An example is below.

`/path/to/source/dir   /path/to/mount/point   none   bind   0 0`

Comment: What do the "none" and 0 0 do?

Comment: "none" represents the file system and "0 0" provide configuration used by [dump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dump) and [fsck](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab), respectively. Since this is an existing path and not a unique disk/file system, empty or disabled values are specified for these fields.

Comment: are source dir and mount point arguments in the same order as for the `mount` command?

Comment: @JohnBachir yes, same order

Answer (score 0):

You should add the appropriate info into [/etc/fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) in order to mount the filesystem at boot.