# Trying to understand symlink behavior with vsftpd

Tags: centos, ftp, symlink, vsftpd

I recently moved my website to a CentOS 6 VPS (from a HyperVM-enabled CentOS 5 VPS).  I set up vsftpd to handle our FTP needs.  I created a local user for everyone who needs to use the FTP.  For my user Joe, he logs in with FileZilla and lands in `/home/joe`.  Joe can use that folder for private storage, but I have put a symlink so he can access public storage at `/var/www/html/storage`.

So in his directory, I did as root:
`ln -s /var/www/html/storage/ storage`

For some reason the ending `/` is necessary, or else `storage` will appear as a file in FileZilla instead of a shortcut to a directory.

Anyway, while in `/home/joe`, when Joe navigates to `storage` his path suddenly becomes `/var/www/html/storage` instead of `/home/joe/storage`.  This makes it hard to navigate back up to the parent folder into his home directory.

**Is there a way to correct this?**

`chroot` is disabled on my server, and that's fine. I  trust my users, but it's just inconvenient for them to be thrown around the filesystem like that via the symlinks.  If I do enable `chroot` then they won't be able to get to `/var/www` at all.

The bizarre thing is that this worked on my previous VPS with HyperVM.  But that one used PureFTP instead of vsftp.  And I think it created virtual users instead of real local users on the machine.  Are virtual users necessary to be able to do symlinks the way I want?

Another solution I researched was using `mount --bind`, but I am unsure if this is the best action to take.  Will it wreck my filesystem to have tons of mount points?  It also just feels improper when `ln -s` ought to be working.  If I SSH into my server as Joe, I am able to go to `/home/joe/storage` in a bash shell.  So why can't I do it in FTP?

As a side note, does this have something to do with `LIST` versus `MLSD` in FTP clients? I have a Mac user who is not able to see the symlinks as symlinks at all, even if I put a trailing `/` in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do the mount --bind option.. as it would at least perserve the pathing in filezilla.

Also doing that if you wanted to enable chroot in vsftp so the user see's /home/user as / it would add more security but the mount --bind would allow the user to still get to that directory while the symlink would not

Comment: All right.  And according to [this other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/141504/mount-bind-persistence-over-reboot) it looks like I have to edit `/etc/fstab` to re-mount all the links after a system reboot.

Comment: Yes that is the best way to do it